# Empty message in gridPanel

Tags: extjs, grid, panel

I'm using Extjs gridPanel to display data. I want to show "No data..." message in gridPanel  when no data available. How to do this ?.

I tried emptyText property but its not worked.

I think emptyText is for gridView not for gridPanel.

Please help me how to show empty data message in gridPanel.(I'm using gridPanel not grid View)

Answer (score 44):

You answered your own question -- it is indeed a GridView property.  So to specify it in the GridPanel (which uses a GridView internally) just do this:

```
myGrid = new Ext.GridPanel({
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No records'
    }
});
```

Per the comments below, you might also include [`deferEmptyText: false`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.view.AbstractView-cfg-deferEmptyText) in the viewConfig for the text to render immediately (otherwise it waits until after the initial store load is complete).

Comment: It seems that you might need call "refresh" on the view of the grid (and defer it) in order to see the empty message: e.g. `myGrid.view.refresh.defer(1, ,myGrid.view);` see [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109611-OPEN-1262-3.3-GridView-emptyText-not-working-at-several-levels.)

Comment: As the link by **Mark Rhodes** also mentions, you can configure your `viewConfig` to also include the parameter `deferEmptyText: false` which will display the empty text immediately.

Comment: Came here from a google search, just want to point out this still works in Ext4 (4.0.7 to be precise)

Comment: The deferEmptyText: false did it for me!! I feel it is un-*******-believable they put it on true by default! Cost me an hour! :-(((

Comment: I can only concur about the defer stuff. I must be missing something as I don't even get why such a thing is needed in the first place...

Comment: @Lawrence Loading a store from a remote source for the first time. Do you want to show a message saying "No items exist?" while the store is loading? At that point you don't know, you need to wait until the load has completed.